# Batch File: IE Browser session AND using a proxy configuration

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, proxy

I have a bit of a challenge here: I want to create a batch file that opens an IE browser session to a specific url -  Easy enough

```
cd C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Internet Explorer"
start iexplore.exe http://tumblr.com
```

**The Challenge:**

How do I configure that bat file so that the connection will go through a proxy server, as you would have configured it in internet options?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`the easiest way - [with a temp .registry file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961):

proxy.reg:

```
Regedit4

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
    "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
    "ProxyServer"="http://ProxyServername:80"
```

the bat:

```
regiedit.exe /s proxy.reg
cd C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Internet Explorer"
start iexplore.exe http://tumblr.com
```

**EDIT**

```
 REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnableRegKey /v 1
```

enables proxy

```
REG add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer /v "http://ProxyServername:80"
```

sets proxy server

In all cases changes of proxy settings via .bat will require administrator privileges.

Comment: thank you npocmaka. If i want to remove the reg entry again after I have run the batch file, what is the quickest and best way?

Comment: with `REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnableRegKey /v 0` you can disable the proxy.With `REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer /va` you delete the proxy value..Not sure how safe is this :-)

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately the regedit does not work...it does not register the registry entry. Could you maybe test it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Things are much simpler than you think:

```
rem dos batch to enable proxy 
reg update "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable=1"
```

and

```
rem dos batch to disable proxy 
reg update "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable=0"
```

You may want to add some `iexplore.exe http://tumblr.com` after this stuff...

So, `reg update some key=value` ... update registry values.  The `"` is there to make the unbelievably existing spaces in keys name enter one argument and not two.